# cfcontent call order perplexing

Tags: javascript, jquery, coldfusion

I'm using CFcontent to stream a spreadsheet to my browser from the server. I'm getting what seems to my novice eyes to be quite anomalous behavior. The streaming is happening, but the code around the streaming is not getting executed, and I can't figure out why.

First, I set up a hidden input (which defaults at "0" and gets toggled to "1" when the user clicks the "Download" button).

```
<cfparam name="txtDoDownload" default="0">
<cfif IsDefined("form.txtDoDownload")>
    <cfset txtDoDownload = form.txtDoDownload>
</cfif>
<cfinput type="hidden" name="txtDoDownload" id="txtDoDownload" value="#txtDoDownload#">
```

Then, I run the "download" code if the hidden input Form.txtDiDownload is 1.

```
<cfoutput>
<cfif IsDefined("Form.txtDoDownload")>
    <!--- THE FOUR ALERTS BELOW DON'T EXECUTE AFTER THE BUTTON IS CLICKED --->
    <!--- BUT THE DOWNLOAD IS STILL HAPPENING --->
    <script>alert("Foo!")</script>
    <script>alert("Form.txtDoDownload: " + #Form.txtDoDownload#)</script>
    <cfif "#Form.txtDoDownload#" EQ 1>
        <script>alert("Downloading . . . ")</script>
    <cfif IsDefined("Alums.Recordcount")>
                <script>alert("In xlDownload")</script>
                <cfset sObj = SpreadsheetNew("AlumniList","true")>
                <cfscript>
                    SpreadsheetAddRows(sObj,Alums); 
                </cfscript>
            <cfspreadsheet action="write" filename="C:\DevRoot\test.xlsx" name="sObj" overwrite="true">
            <cfheader name="Content-Disposition" value="inline; filename=temp.xlsx">
            <cfcontent deletefile="yes" type="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet" file="C:\wwwroot\test.xlsx"> 
        </cfif>
        <script>resetDownload();</script>
        </cfif>
    </cfif>
</cfoutput>
```

Here's the button:

```
<cfinput type="button" value="Download to Excel" id="btnDLXL" name="btnDLXL" onClick="initDownload()">
```

Here's the Javascript that's executed when the button is clicked:

```
function initDownload() {
    $('#txtDoDownload').val(1);
    alert("initDownload (txtDoDownload): " + $('#txtDoDownload').val());
    $('#AlumForm').submit();
}
```

The download happens fine, but none of the alerts around the download are getting triggered after the button is clicked (a few get triggered before the button gets clicked, on the first pass). Is this an "order of execution issue?"  Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: One thing I can think of: is it that on a submit, CF can only either return a page, or stream a file, but not do both on the same submit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@user3738377 is correct in their comment. The request is - as instructed by the `<cfheader>` and `<cfcontent>` tags - responding with the `test.xlsx`, so it can't *also* respond with the mark-up above it. So the mark-up never gets sent to the browser, so can never execute.

You will need to move the JS interaction to the end of the previous request: after they press the button, but before the request for the XLS file is made.

Comment: A quick follow-up. I do have JS prior to the XLS download request, but the JS doesn't seem to be executing. In my code above, after the button is clicked, but before the XLS download stream is initiated, I use JS to toggle the hidden input (txtDoDownload) to "1", but in my console, the Form field txtDoDownload remains at "0." Also, strangely, the download is only supposed to execute when Form.txtDoDownload EQ "1" and the download continually executes on any submit (even a submit from another button), so txtDoDownload must be stuck at 1. Any way to update the hidden inputafter the XLS request?

Comment: Post this as a new question mate; this isn't a back-and-forth discussion forum.